# Manage WSUS remotely

Tags: wsus

How to remotely administer the WSUS from a workstation "windows xp"?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the documentation, which is rather clear about exactly how to go about it. I suspect there's a few other important points you may have missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on which version of WSUS you are running.

2.0 there is a webpage you go to on the server that is running WSUS (if i'm remembering correctly it's `http://<servername>/WSUS`)

With 3.0 you need to run the installer on your workstation and select console only installation, then you manage it through the MMC snap-in.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, does it require special permission ?

do i need to use the same credential for wsus admin ?

Comment: yep uses your windows authentication token to give your rights, if you can manage it on the server you'll be able to manage it from your workstation.

Comment: wsus ver is 3.0

Comment: @lyad: Then you should be good to go if you can manage WSUS from the console of the server, just log into your workstation with the same credentials. Otherwise you'll have to get your user the correct permissions.

Comment: this is great info thanks.

what is the minimum permission required for this ?

Answer (score 1):

For those of you trying to use the Console of a Server 2008 R2 WSUS Server and a WSUS Management console from Windows 8 Pro.  You have to switch the port to 80 from the default suggestion or you will not be able to connect. 
I hope this helps someone out.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know as I was getting an error message saying IIS was not running. Changed the port to 80 and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This depends, WSUS is normally installed on a Windows Server (either 2003, or 2010), so you can do this many ways.

The easiest way is to enable remote desktop on the server where WSUS is installed, and use the remote desktop client that comes with windows XP to manage that server, including WSUS.

While you can use an MMC snap-in to manage WSUS, you must install it on every machine you wish to use to manage WSUS, where as the terminal services client is installed by default on every windows XP machine.  (Start, Run, mstsc)

Comment: The MMC snap-in is available on Microsoft's website.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx
The WSUS server download also includes the management console mentioned below.  Simply run the same installer on your desktop and you should have an option to install the MMC Snap-In

Comment: thank you , i think i have to install the same pre-request on win xp:
.net framework
report viewer
mmc 3.0
administrative console

Answer (score -1):

Map a drive to the server(s) you need to connect to using an account created and given WSUS Admin access. Then connect to the WSUS server with the Admin console.

Comment: Please note that this question is 13 years old and no longer on topic on Server Fault since Windows XP is long out of support.